# What amount of cash I can take with me when going from Canada to USA?

Tags: usa, money

What amount of cash I can take with me when going from Canada to USA?
I want to travel to US and want to take ~ 12000$ with me. DO I need to declare it and pay any fee?

Comment: $12K cash?  Do you need a lift from the airport? :)

Comment: The US requires you to report it.  They don't prohibit it, nor do they charge any fee.

Comment: There is no limit; you can carry as much as you are comfortable with. You just have to declare any amount above $10,000 and be able to justify the source and the reason you are carrying the cash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Travelers leaving or entering the U.S. with more than $10,000 (in any form, that includes cash or checks) are required to declare it by filling out a Report of International Transportation of Currency or Monetary Instruments ([FinCEN 105](http://www.fincen.gov/forms/files/fin105_cmir.pdf)). This applies even if you are passing  through the U.S. in transit to other countries.

Source: [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/about_5445167_laws-bringing-cash-america.html#ixzz266aafaCc)

Comment: FinCEN 105 is quite specific as to what is considered a "monetary instrument" and ordinary checks made out to a named recipient (and not endorsed) are excluded.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Heidel's point that the US cares you are taking more than $10,000 out of the USA, Canada cares that you are bringing more than $10,000 in. The form you will fill out on arrival is at http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/forms-formulaires/e311-eng.pdf and you can see they want to know if you have that amount of cash on you.

According to http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/security-securite/cbcr-dmte/menu-eng.html you don't have to pay any fee, and you are allowed to bring the money, but you MUST tell them about it. Just allow some time to have a conversation with the CBSA on arrival.

Comment: I believe you've got this the wrong way around. The direction of travel is Canada -> US.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I'll leave the answer though, because a searcher might be interested in the other direction